# Independent Event Complements

Tags: probability

I have the following homework assignment that I've already finished, but am confused on whether I've gotten right/wrong, and was hoping someone could help explain so I understand the problem better.

> An oil exploration company currently has two active projects, one in Asia and the other in Europe. Let A be the event that the Asian projet is successful and B be the event that the European project is successful. Suppose that A and B are independent events with P(A)=0.4 and P(B)=0.7
>
> a.) If the Asian project is not successful, what is the probability that the European project is also not successful? Explain your reasoning.
>
> b.) What is the probability that at least one of the two projects will be successful?
>
> c.) Given that at least one of the two projects is successful, what is the probability that only the Asian project is successful?"

Here is what I've gotten for each part:

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B) = (.4)(.7) = .28 $$

a.) $P(B^c) = 1 - 0.7 = 0.3 $

b.) $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = .4 + .7 - .28 = .82$

c.) $P(A) - P(A \cap B) = .4 - .28 = .12 $
    $.12/.82 = .146$

I am confused in that the two events are independent of each other and the book states that for part a the answer should be .126 instead of what I got. Am I doing these problems correctly or am I committing some error?

Comment: Part a) is correctly done.

Comment: So do I need to get $P(B^c | A^c)$ or not for part a? I originally thought I was correct and there may be a chance the book is wrong, but I don't see how to get 0.126 as the answer for part a

Comment: You are right, $B^c$ and $A^c$ are independent. But if you *really really* feel like it, you can calculate. We have $\Pr(B^c|A^c)=\frac{\Pr(B^c\cap A^c)}{\Pr(A^c)}$. After some grinding you will get $0.3$.

Comment: Ah, I guess I may have stumbled into one of those few times that the book is incorrect with part a. For the other parts my answers were the same as the book's but I wasn't sure if there may have been other mistakes that I had not noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you got part (a) right, while the explanation to your solution would be that $A^C$ and $B^C$ are independent.

Note that even though it is quite intuitive that "$A$ and $B$ are independent $\rightarrow$ $A^C$ and $B^C$ are independent", I think it isn't completely trivial.
(You can find some proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1962698/579869), though I bet you would succeed in proving it by yourself.)

Answer (score -1):

c) (p(A) - p(A n B))/(p(A) + p(B) - p(A n B))

With your numbers

.4 - (.4 * .7) / (.4 + .7 - (.4 * .7))

Answer (score -3):

(a) This question belongs to "conditional model"
But since A and B are independent 
You may take directly p(B not)=0.3

Reason: independent means

P(A .B)=P(A).P(B)

Comment: For the next problem  (b)at least one of the two projects will be success.  = 1- P(no project will success). = 1- P(Anot).P(Bnot)=1 -(0.6)(0.3)=0.82 answer