# Prove that if events A and B are independent, then the complement events of A and B are also independent.

Tags: probability

I know that:
$$\begin{gathered}P\left(A\cap B\right)=P\left(A\right)P\left(B\right)\\
P\left(A^{C}\right)=1-P\left(A\right)\\
P\left(B^{C}\right)=1-P\left(B\right)
\end{gathered}
$$

My proof so far:
$$\begin{gathered}P\left(A^{C}\cap B^{C}\right)=\left(1-P\left(A\right)\right)\left(1-P\left(B\right)\right)=\\
1-P\left(B\right)-P\left(A\right)+P\left(A\right)P\left(B\right)=1-P\left(B\right)-P\left(A\right)+P\left(A\cap B\right)
\end{gathered}
$$

After that, I'm stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $=1-P(A \cup B)$... Also your first line after "What I have so far:" is what you're trying to prove, not what you have.

Answer (score 56):

Assume $A$ and $B$ are independent. Then
\begin{align}
P(A^c \cap B^c) &= P( (A \cup B)^c) \quad \tag{by De Morgan's Law}\\
&= 1 - P(A \cup B) \\
&= 1 - P(A) - P(B) + P(A \cap B) \\
&= 1 - P(A) - P(B) + P(A)P(B) \\
&= (1-P(A))(1-P(B)) \\
&= P(A^c)P(B^c).
\end{align}

Comment: The addition law says that (∪) = ()+()-(∩). Why are you doing the opposite in the second line?

Comment: Maybe we should also mention DeMorgans law as a good way to understand why the first line is true.

Comment: @nicholsonjf That whole term is preceded by a -, so with parentaccess it's 1-(()+()-(∩))

Answer (score 13):

[gradient23's proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1962737/579869) is great, in my opinion, but I would like to show another proof that seems more intuitive to me, though much less rigorous.

The proof is based on a verbal definition of independence from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)):

> two events are independent [...] if the occurrence of one does not affect the probability of occurrence of the other

In addition, we use the fact that independence is symmetric.

The (non-rigorous) proof:

- We assume that $A$ and $B$ are independent.
- By definition, the occurrence of  $A$ doesn't affect the probability of $B$.
- Thus, the occurrence of  $A$ also doesn't affect the probability of $B^C$.
- So by definition, $A$ and $B^C$ are also independent, which by definition again means that the occurrence of  $B^C$ doesn't affect the probability of $A$.
  (Here we used the symmetry of independence.)
- Therefore, the occurrence of $B^C$ also doesn't affect the probability of $A^C$.
- So by definition, $B^C$ and $A^C$ are also independent.

---

One could convert the proof to the language of math:
$$\begin{gathered}A\text{ and }B\,\text{are independent}\\
\downarrow\\
P\left(B|A\right)=P\left(B\right)\\
\downarrow\\
1-P\left(B^{C}|A\right)=1-P\left(B^{C}\right)\\
\downarrow\\
P\left(B^{C}|A\right)=P\left(B^{C}\right)\\
\downarrow\\
A\text{ and }B^{C}\,\text{are independent}\\
\downarrow\\
P\left(A|B^{C}\right)=P\left(A\right)\\
\downarrow\\
1-P\left(A^{C}|B^{C}\right)=1-P\left(A^{C}\right)\\
\downarrow\\
P\left(A^{C}|B^{C}\right)=P\left(A^{C}\right)\\
\downarrow\\
B^{C}\text{ and }A^{C}\,\text{are independent}
\end{gathered}
$$

But now we used conditional probabilities, which might be a problem in case $P(A)=0$ or $P(B^C)=0$ ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110112/probability-conditional-on-a-zero-probability-event) is a discussion about this problem).

Answer (score 4):

As you have found :

$$P(A') = 1-P(A)$$

$$P(B') = 1- P(B)$$

Now clearly $P(A')P(B') =1 - [ P(A) + P(B)]  + P(A \cap B)$

From set algebra we know that
$P(A) + P(B) = P(A \cup B) + P(A\cap B)$
Substituting, we have $P(A')P(B') = P([A\cup B]')$

Now from De morgans law we know that:

$[A\cup B]' = [A' \cap B']$

Substituting, we have $P(A')P(B') = P(A' \cap B')$ , as required.

Answer (score 0):

By definition if two events are independent then $P(A | B)=P(A)=P(A/B')$.

So, $P(A/B)=P(A \cap B)/P(B)=P(A)$ and hence by multiplying both sides by $P(B)$ we get $P(A \cap B)= P(A)P(B)$.

Hence proved.