# a simple issue on Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

Here is my question: I know if A & B are independent, P(A|B) = P(A); But If A and B are independent, is it true that: P(A'|B) = P (A')???

Comment: what does A' mean?

Comment: Hint: $P(A|B) + P(A'|B) = 1$

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron My **guess**, which could be mistaken, is that $A'$ represents the complement of $A$.  Assuming so, the answer to the posted question is **yes**, if $A$ is independent of $B$, then $A'$ is independent of $B$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Complement of A

Comment: The question has already been proven on mathSE.  You might search for conditional probability, or other tags.  I didn't want to go to the trouble of re-creating the proof, since I remember the issue already being broached on mathSE.  I am unsure what mathSE posting has this issue, however.

Comment: @A.Webb You're Right! I ain't so good in math; so THAT was the key you just mentioned. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2661923 tnx a lot

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1962698/prove-that-if-events-a-and-b-are-independent-then-the-complement-events-of-a-an/2922539  This has been proven on stack exchange.  How do I label this question a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof

$$P(A'|B) =\frac{P(A' \cap B)}{P(B)}$$
But $P(A'  \cap  B) = P(A)  - P(A n B)$
Thus $$P(A'| B)  = P(B) \frac{1 - P(A)}{P(B)} = P(A')$$ since
$1 - P(A) = P(A')$.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question might've looked weird; But believe me, I don't like this subject much. That's why I couldn't solve such a simple question.
Anyway, as @A.Webb commented: $P(A'|B) + P(A|B) = 1$, which could be written like this: $P(A'|B) = 1 - P(A|B)$.

As we had in hypothesis, A and B are independent, so $P(A|B) = P(A)$.
Hence: $$P(A'|B) = 1 - P(A)$$
And we know $A$ and $A'$ are complements and to sum these two up, equals to $1$. Then $P(A'|B)$ MUST be equal to $P(A')$.